# Switch LocalDB to SQL server db with MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created new project under MVC5 with individual authentication. Then I have build it and register a test user to test login system. I already migrated my database table LocalDB to my SQL server.

Now created connection string to connect SQL server but the problem is it is still using my old LocalDB which saving data to App_Data folder.

Can you give me some advice to switch this LocalDB to my SQL server? I already created "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" but how to connect it with my SQL server? Any idea? Any question welcome.

Comment: You created a connection string for your sql server, but are you _using_ it? Simply remove all references to your localDB from your config and see what happens - likely you cannot connect at all to a database. For the rest, we can't see from here how you (try to) connect to anything, so we can;t see what could be wrong without you showing what you tried...

Comment: @oerkelens you are correct. i have commented out all of my 2 connection string form Web.Config but then i still can login with my test user which i was created on starting! isn't it strange?

Comment: You said you migrated your database from LocalDB to your SQL Server, that would bring over your "test user" with it.

Answer (score -1):

This Guide was very useful for me :

https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

Follow all the easy steps for move your LocalDB table to SQL server db Table.

**1.  Inspect the Web.config File Connection String and Connect to Local Database**

Change the defaut connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApp-20190226025646.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApp-20190226025646;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To your connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PC-YWGSB;Initial Catalog=WebApp;user id=admin;password=admin" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**2. Then use the commands for DB Migration "Codefirst"**

This is the official guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

*From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.
At the PM> prompt enter the following commands:*

> 1. enable-migrations
> 2. add-migration InitialCreate
> 3. update-database

The database will be created automatically during migration. 
If you already have one make sure to backup all tables.