# Switch from LocalDB to SQL Server DB MVC5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, database-connection, connection-string

I have a MVC5 project with individual authentication.

Now I want to move from `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` to another SQL Server database.

I've tried to change connection string from this :

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect
Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

to this:

```
Data Source=PC-GABRI;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

And the application is still using localDB instead of my new SQL Server DB.

I have already migrated the database and roles.

I have also tried to comment all of my connection string form `Web.Config` but my application is still working and I can login with my "test" user.

I can't find anything on the web about this!

PS.

Related Questions: [Switch LocalDB to SQL server db with MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651634/switch-localdb-to-sql-server-db-with-mvc5/54947332#54947332)

We have the same problem!

**UPDATE 1**

DB Instance:

[image: Database Instances]

Connection String:

[image]

The instances are running correctly.

Tell me if you need more info.

---

### UPDATE

This Guide was very useful for me :

https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

Follow all the easy steps for move your LocalDB table to SQL server db Table.

**1.  Inspect the Web.config File Connection String and Connect to Local Database**

Change the defaut connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApp-20190226025646.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApp-20190226025646;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To your connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PC-YWGSB;Initial Catalog=WebApp;user id=admin;password=admin" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**2. Then use the commands for DB Migration "Codefirst"**

This is the official guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

*From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.
At the PM> prompt enter the following commands:*

> 1. enable-migrations
> 2. add-migration InitialCreate
> 3. update-database

The database will be created automatically during migration. 
If you already have one make sure to backup all tables.

Comment: Could you please post your code plus the full EF configuration?

Comment: You need a Server and an instance of the server in the connection string.  Open SQL Server Management Studio to get instance of the server.   See login window to get instance.

Comment: I've updated the question! Thanks!